# Movement of an electron on an equipotential surface

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, charge, work

> Two opposing charges, $+Q$ and $-Q$, are spaced apart by a distance $R$. The first is made to describe a complete circumference around the second. How much is the work done by the electric field in that way? ...

Why is the answer "zero"? Should the equipotential surface no longer be a sphere because the field is different now? Or does the presence of the field of a load not affect its course itself or how are the fields of other charges?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that moving one particle does not affect the other in a way that changes its position from the center of the circle, since the movement is done on a equipotential surface of the field, no work **by one particle is done on the other.** But there is a catch:

The electrostatic equations itself says that this system *cannot be maintained in a stable stationary equilibrium configuration solely by the electrostatic interaction of the charges* (Wikipedia: Earnshaw theorem), so in a sense you are right to believe that in an actual situation a net work should be done on the system; actually, this will be the one needed to mantain the particle on its position at the center.Note though that this work applied on the system is external, so there is not a contradiction with the last paragraph.

Comment: This is a great answer. It explains the raw physics concept, but also explains why that concept appears to clash with intuition.

Comment: Thanks, I believe that Earnshaw´s theorem should have a more significat role on Electromagnetics courses, we could avoid a lot of misconceptions.

Answer (score 0):

The standard definition of equipotential surface :

The surface for which work done to move a charge from any point on the surface to any other point on the surface is zero, is called an equipotential surface.

The unit charge also spreads out its electric field but that doesn't interfere with the result that the work done is $zero$ when this charge is moved on an equipotential surface. The equipotential surfaces will retain their shape in the absence or presence of the unit charge (if we are calculating work done on the unit charge).

In a dipole the equipotential surface is different, and the work done on a third charge will be zero when it is moved on these surfaces.

[image]

Your question is similar to this case. You are setting up the electric field which is the net result of the two charges. You don't have to do that.

The positive charge's electric field doesn't interfere with the equipotential surface around the negative charge which was there initially.

The work done for the positive charge will still be zero if it is moved on these surfaces.

We only consider the electric field of the source to determine the work done on a different charge. We do not consider the electric field which is due to both the charges to get the equipotential surfaces.